# How to remove the closing user input value in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, break

I'm trying to create a program that stores user input in arrays, up to 50 numbers, and before displaying the numbers back to the user. The user can cancel the counting by inputting -999. However I don't want -999 to be shown, but I can't seem to remove the value without causing ALL the numbers to not be posted to the user. What am I doing wrong?

```
#define INPUT 50
int main() {
int i;
int userInput[INPUT];

for (i = 0; i < INPUT; i++) {
    printf("Enter up to 50 numbers: (-999 to quit): ");
    scanf("%i", &userInput[i]);
    if (userInput[i] == -999) {
        break; 
    }
} 

for (i = 0; i < INPUT && i && userInput[i] !=999; i++) {
    printf("%i. %i\n", i + 1, userInput[i]);
    if (userInput[i] == -999) {
        break;
    }
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: This part will fail already for the first number: `&& i `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues with your code.

1. Simplify the second `for` clause:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < INPUT; i++) {
   ```

   If you leave the simple `i` condition, the second loop will never execute.
2. As Mike said, `break` *before* displaying the terminating number -999.

Answer (score 0):

You do first the printf and then ckeck if -999.
Try to change:

```
for (i = 0; i < INPUT; i++) {
    if (userInput[i] == -999) {
        break;
    }
    printf("%i. %i\n", i + 1, userInput[i]);
}
```